# Robot Framework: Open a chrome browser without launching URL

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I want to open a chrome browser in Robot framework which has no URL launched in it.

for ex :

```
'Open Browser | http://google.com | chrome'
```

will open chrome browser and launch the google page.

I want to open a chrome browser with no URL launched.
I have tried the below two things,

```
'Open Browser | ${EMPTY} | chrome'

'Open Browser | NONE | chrome'
```

They above works, it opens an empty browser , but in the result the test fails. Please can somebody give an input on this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to create a Chrome instance without any URL being passed through to it, use

```
Create Webdriver | Chrome
```

There are more options for this which can be found [here](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Create%20Webdriver). Generally, they say it is better to `Open Browser`, but if you must create an instance without a URL being passed through and need it to pass, use `Create Webdriver`.

Comment: Any time, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 9):

You can use the url `about:blank`:

```
Open Browser | about:blank | chrome
```

Comment: Was going to suggest this as well. I personally prefer this solution to the accepted answer, +1